# Ephemeral port numbers: Same server port after establishment?

Tags: tcp, connection, client-server, port

If have a webserver running at port 80 and someone connects from a client using randomly assigned port x, then the server knows which port to reply to. However, at that time on, does the communication to the server continue on port 80 from then on (assigned a file descriptor to socket-pair ip:x), or does the server also delegate further communication onto another randomly assigned port of itself; y?

So what I am really asking is: When the server replies -does it reply with a source port of 80 back for further communication?

Comment: You don't really reply "on" a port, you reply *to* a port. (And also *from* a port.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If have a webserver running at port 80 and someone connects from a client using randomly assigned port x

*At the client end.*

> then the server knows on what port to reply.

The server replies via the same connection it received the request on. What happens below that is up to TCP. It isn't 'knowledge' of the server application.

> However, at that time on, does the communication to the server continue on port 80 from then on

Yes.

> (assigned a file descriptor to socket-pair ip:x)

To the socket *quad* {local-IP, local-port, remote-IP, remote port}.

> or does the server also delegate further communication onto another randomly assigned port of itself;

No.

> So what I am really asking is: When the server replies -does it reply with a source port of 80 back for further communication?

Yes.

Comment: Excellent answer. Everything I wanted to know!